# Android ViewPager+Seekbar synchronization

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-seekbar

I wanted to implement the fake drag by of ViewPager with the help of Seekbar control. For that I have tried following code, but it is not working as I wanted, any help would be appreciated, have a look on the code I was using:

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnSeekBarChangeListener {
SeekBar fontSeekBar;
ViewPager viewPager;

int maxOffset;
int currentOffset;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fontSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.fontSeekBar);
    fontSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (viewPager.isFakeDragging()) {
         int offset = (int) ((maxOffset / 100.0) * progress);

        int dragby = -1 * (offset - currentOffset);
        Log.d("DRAGBY", "" + progress);
        viewPager.fakeDragBy(dragby);

        currentOffset = offset;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    maxOffset = viewPager.getWidth();

    viewPager.beginFakeDrag();
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.endFakeDrag();

    currentOffset = 0;

    seekBar.setProgress(0);
}

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "Map", "Details", "News" };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return 1f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }
}
```

}

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.seeknslide.MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/fontSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> According to this code ViewPager will slide its one page after seekbar is seeked to its MAX but I want a **proper synchronization of view pager with seekbar**, so that amount of seekbar dragged will be equal to amount of view pager slided, and this should happen in both direction, i.e. when I drag seekbar from left to right, viewpager should also drag from left to right and when seekbar is dragged from right to left then viewpager should also act accordingly.

**Any help will be appreciated.**
**Screenshot is shown as follows**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSIVo.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzwiv.png

Comment: can you show the screenshot also

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us8w2g9YXC4... do you want some thing like this?

Comment: @navya I cant add screenshot to my question as I will be needing atleast 10 repo for that. But yes this is the thing I want, as you have shown in youtube link, but in a more synchronized manner. :)

Comment: tonny ok....wait..now you will be able to add screenshot

Comment: To be more precise I need all the viewpager pages to scroll when seekbar is seeked to its MAX position, here in this video only one page is scrolled when seekbar is seeked to its MAX.

Comment: ok...can you give me your sample code in zip file?

Comment: all the code I have already shown in the question only you have to create three fragments for view pager, rest nothing is there.